# Why does delete ignore deleting objects in an arrary except the first one?

Tags: c++, object, new-operator, delete-operator

I'm trying to create 4 Students objects on the heap. When I attempt to delete them, only the first one is deleted.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class Student{
private:
    int ID;
    int score;
public:
    void setID(int num);
    int getID();
    void setScore(int num);
    int getScore();
};
void Student::setID(int num)
{
    ID = num;
}
int Student::getID()
{
    return ID;
}
void Student::setScore(int num)
{
    score = num;
}
int Student::getScore()
{
    return score;
}
class Creator
{
public:
    static int nextID;
    Student* getObject();
};
int Creator::nextID = 0;
Student* Creator::getObject()
{
    Creator::nextID++;
    Student* temp = new Student();
    temp->setID(Creator::nextID);
    return temp;
}
int main()
{
    Creator maker;
    Student *pupil[4];
    int mark = 70;
    for(std::size_t i = 0; i < (sizeof(pupil)/sizeof(pupil[0])); i++)
    {
        pupil[i] = maker.getObject();
        pupil[i]->setScore(mark);
        mark += 10;
    }
    for(std::size_t i = 0; i < (sizeof(pupil)/sizeof(pupil[0])); i++)
    {
        cout<< "Sudent ID: "<<pupil[i]->getID()<<" has score of: "<<pupil[i]->getScore()<<endl;
    }
    //attempting to delete
    for(std::size_t i = 0; i < (sizeof(pupil)/sizeof(pupil[0])); i++)
    {
        delete pupil[i];
    }
    //confirm deletion
    for(std::size_t i = 0; i < (sizeof(pupil)/sizeof(pupil[0])); i++)
    {
        cout<< "Sudent ID: "<<pupil[i]->getID()<<" has score of: "<<pupil[i]->getScore()<<endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Here is the output:

```
Sudent ID: 1 has score of: 70
Sudent ID: 2 has score of: 80
Sudent ID: 3 has score of: 90
Sudent ID: 4 has score of: 100
```

After deletion:

```
Sudent ID: 7864516 has score of: 7864516 
Sudent ID: 2 has score of: 80
Sudent ID: 3 has score of: 90
Sudent ID: 4 has score of: 100
```

It looks as if only the first object was deleted but the rest still exist. How do I delete the four object to avoid memory leaks?

Comment: This line `Student* temp = new Student();` should be `Student* temp = new Student;`

Comment: If you access memory that has been freed, it might still contain the same data as before; it might be that no one wrote other data in that memory. If you want to be sure that you have no memory leaks, run your program with `valgrind`

Comment: Just tried changing ` Student* temp = new Student();` to ` Student* temp = new Student;` and I still got the same output.

Comment: @EdHeal Those are exactly equivalent here.

Comment: @CodyGray: you can't use `delete[]` in this case because the array is not being allocated with `new[]`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> When I attempt to delete them, only the first one is deleted.

That isn't true. All of your `Student`s are, in fact, `delete`d. You could verify this by adding a a destructor to `Student` that logs when it's called - you'd see it called 4 times.

The misunderstanding comes from what deleting actually means. Deleting does not imply that the memory is zeroed out - just that it's available for future use. It's a waste of operations to actually go ahead and zero things out - so typically that doesn't happen. What you are doing - reading data from deleted memory - is **undefined behavior**. It happens to look like the previous values, but it could just as easily be zero. Or random garbage.

Comment: Or the sequenced genome of Jon Skeet.

Comment: @PreferenceBean I don't think that would fit in the storage of my machine.

Comment: You must have a very old machine, then, as the human genome takes up around 1.5GB. Or are we saying that Jon Skeet is not human.... hmm...

Comment: @PreferenceBean [Cue 5th Element] All life on earth is composed of 4 base pairs. Jon Skeet has over 200.